# Reuse value from 'callonce read' in multiple scenario's

Tags: karate

I'm trying to reuse an orderId which is created by an API for testing call to another API.
I create 1 order and want to reuse that id in a Scenario Outline.
The issue is that the Background is executed multiple times, so the orderId is overwritten by response.orderId the next time.

How could I ensure that the orderId is only set once and not overwritten later?

My feature-file:

```
Feature: GET-order

Background:
 * url demoUrl
 Given path '/getOrder'
 * def request = read('./request_template.json')
 * callonce read('./create_order.feature')
 * def orderId = response.orderId #this also should be done once

Scenario Outline: Test different values fromid
 * print 'orderId: ' + orderId
 * set request.orderId = orderId
 * set request.fromId = <_fromId>
 When method GET
 Then status 200
 Examples:
   | _fromId |
   | '1'     |
   | '2'     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Please the documentation on [how to return values](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files) from a `call` (or `callonce`):

Try this change:

```
Background:
 * url demoUrl
 * path '/getOrder'
 * def payload = read('./request_template.json')
 * def result = callonce read('./create_order.feature')
 * def orderId = result.response.orderId
```